# coral micro controller Object Detection models

Tags: object-detection-api, google-coral

Try to run the coral micro example detect_objects with an customer trained models.
Running the same script as google provided on https://colab.research.google.com/github/google-coral/tutorials/blob/master/retrain_ssdlite_mobiledet_qat_tf1.ipynb.

On the example code, I changed the model path

```
constexpr char kModelPath[] ="/models/my_model.tflite";
```

On the CMakeLists.txt

```
`add_executable_m7(detect_objects
    detect_objects.cc
    DATA
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/models/my_model.tflite`
)
```

build and flash it. And then I encounter an error

Node TFLite_Detection_PostProcess (number 1) failed to invoke with status 1
Failed to detect image from camera.

I had compare the SSDLite MobileDet model download from coral website https://coral.ai/models/object-detection/ and load it into netron[image]

I found a slight different from the one I trained
[image]

Any idea what cause the differences?
Or do I miss any step to run a customer trained model on coral?

I had tried all the tutorial example on how to trained a custom model
all end up in the same result
https://coral.ai/models/object-detection/ under the training script
But I can download a pretrained models and run it on micro controller from https://coral.ai/models/object-detection/ under the trained models session

I tried to swap the resolver to allOpsResolver but it doesn't work

```
`tflite::MicroErrorReporter error_reporter;
  tflite::MicroMutableOpResolver<3> resolver;
  // tflite::AllOpsResolver resolver;
  resolver.AddDequantize();
  resolver.AddDetectionPostprocess();
  resolver.AddCustom(kCustomOp, RegisterCustomOp());`
```

the script I use to export and convert to tflite

```
ModelDir="/mnt/saved_models/0105_model_lowlr"
LastCheckpoint="/model.ckpt-500"
PipelineConfig=$ModelDir"/pipeline.config"
OutputDir=$ModelDir"/export"

python3 object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py \
  --pipeline_config_path=$PipelineConfig \
  --trained_checkpoint_prefix=$ModelDir$LastCheckpoint \
  --output_directory=$OutputDir \
  --add_postprocessing_op=true

tflite_convert \
  --output_file="$OutputDir/model.tflite" \
  --graph_def_file="$OutputDir/tflite_graph.pb" \
  --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
  --input_arrays="normalized_input_image_tensor" \
  --output_arrays="TFLite_Detection_PostProcess,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3" \
  --mean_values=128 \
  --std_dev_values=128 \
  --input_shapes=1,320,320,3 \
  --change_concat_input_ranges=false \
  --allow_nudging_weights_to_use_fast_gemm_kernel=true \
  --allow_custom_ops
```

python 3.6.9
tf 1.15.5
tf.slim 1.1.0